# Class template argument deduction of member variables

Tags: c++, c++17, ctad

In C++17 I am allowed to use `Foo` in the following example without empty template argument brackets thanks to class template argument deduction:

```
template<typename T = int>
struct Foo{};

int main(){
    Foo f;    // before C++17 you had to write "Foo<> f;"
}
```

Why am I not allowed to use the same syntax for class members?

```
template<typename T = int>
struct Foo{};

struct Foo2{
    Foo f{};  ///< error: invalid use of template-name 'Foo' without an argument list
};

int main(){
    Foo2 f2;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Nobody, IIRC, proposed it.
2. Presumably for the same reason we don't deduce anything from default member initializers: they are not always used - a constructor can override them by explicitly specify a different initializer.

Comment: And formally, template argument deduction is performed when the name of a class template is used as the type of an object being constructed.